# How to Group By Array Objects that Contains a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array

```
[<br>
  &nbsp;{CONTRACT_ID: 420, DEDUCTIONS: "Warehouse Fixture - Generic Double", AMOUNT: 600} <br>
  &nbsp;{CONTRACT_ID: 420, DEDUCTIONS: "Warehouse Fixture - Rack", AMOUNT: 750} <br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Freight Incoming", AMOUNT: 10, RATE:2} <br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Freight Outgoing", AMOUNT: 30, RATE:2} <br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Warehouse", AMOUNT: 500} <br>
]
```

And Here is what i want as a result:

```
[<br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Warehouse Fixture", AMOUNT: 1350} <br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Freight", AMOUNT: 40} <br>
  &nbsp;{DEDUCTIONS: "Warehouse", AMOUNT: 500} <br>
]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what you did and how you want jquery /javascript? your effort needed, rather than every you want from us

Comment: I'm sorry, Javascript will be better @Ajay2707

Answer (score 0):

For this example, the code below is fine, but you need to define more specific grouping logic.

```
const indexedResult = {};

initialArray.forEach(obj => {
  let key;

  if ("CONTRACT_ID" in obj) {
    key = obj.DEDUCTIONS.split(/ - /, 1)[0];
  } else if ("RATE" in obj) {
    key = obj.DEDUCTIONS.split(/ /, 1)[0];
  } else {
    key = obj.DEDUCTIONS;
  }

  if (key in indexedResult) {
    indexedResult[key].AMOUNT += obj.AMOUNT;
  } else {
    indexedResult[key] = {
      DEDUCTIONS: key,
      AMOUNT: obj.AMOUNT
    };
  }
});

const result = Object.keys(indexedResult).map(key => indexedResult[key]);
```